# How can I optimize my merge sort algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, sorting, data-structures

I have written a merge sort algorithm which is taking much more time than bubble sort and quick sort.

Can someone please help me optimize the same? Here is the code.

```
public static void mergeSort(List<MyElement> array, int left, int right, Comparator<? super MyElement> comp) {
    int mid;
    if(right > left) {
        mid = (right + left) / 2;
        mergeSort(array, left, mid,comp);
        mergeSort(array, mid+1, right, comp);
        merge(array, left, mid, right, comp);
    }

}


public static void merge(List<MyElement> array, int left, int mid, int right, Comparator<? super MyElement> comp) {

    PriorityQueue<MyElement> queue = 
            new PriorityQueue<MyElement>(50, comp);
    for(int i = left; i <= mid;  i++) {
        queue.offer(array.get(i));
    }
    for(int i = mid + 1; i < right;  i++) {
        queue.offer(array.get(i));
    }



    int index = left;
    while(index < right && queue.size() != 0) {
        MyElement item  = queue.remove();
        array.set(index, item);
        index++;
    }

}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: On what size lists are you testing this? And the unnecessary priority queues are possibly part of the problem.

Comment: thanks for looking into it. There are 10 odd elements in the list to be sorted. And the algorithm *has to* use priority queues. Any suggestion optimize with the use of priority queues?

Comment: could you post the problematic input?

Comment: Here is my input :Zack,18.3,2009-10-05
Albert,16.1,2010-08-13
John,4.4,2011-02-21
Bob,22.5,2012-04-17
Peter,15.4,2008-10-05
Richard,76.1,2013-08-13
Alice,41.2,2014-02-21
Sam,20.9,2015-04-17
Rich,7.1,2013-08-13
Alex,4.2,2014-02-21
Samuel,10.9,2015-04-17 I am sorting the middle value in each element.

Comment: Try using much larger inputs (like 1 million elements) to have a better idea of speedup due to algorithmic complexity. Do you have to do a merge sort with priority queues? If so, the most correct answer is probably "that's dumb, I won't do it.". If it's just any sort, then you put everything into a priority queue then pull it all out, which is heap sort.

Comment: you said `is taking much more time than bubble sort and quick sort`? shouldn't be instantaneous? there only 10 elements? how long does it take to finish?

Comment: Looking at your code, you also don't seem to be clear on whether `right` is inclusive or exclusive. You should probably think about that carefully, and then be consistent in your application of that decision.

Comment: If the algorithm *has to* use priority queues, then you don't even need any merge logic. Just stuff everything into the priority queue, and when you read it back out, it'll be all sorted for you.

Comment: Here is my execution times.. Bubble Sort Execution Time : 46920
Quick Sort Execution Time : 52296
Merge Sort Execution Time : 255615 which is in nano secs

Comment: That is exactly what I am doing in merge! I am just enqueing and dequeing.. I am just checking for the left and right index while updating the list

Comment: @user2805924 The point is, you should just do this once for the entire list. Nothing else. And as I mentioned earlier, run it for more elements than 10 if you want to see discernible differences and asymptotic behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in your merge method. The left and right halves are already sorted, there is no need for a priority queue. The halves were sorted by the recursive calls to `mergeSort` happening before the `merge`. Just compare the first element of each half and take the smaller one.

Also, the `array` parameter is defined as a `List`. Accessing individual elements may be costly unless it is an `ArrayList`.